# Measuring strong coupling constant

Tags: experimental-physics, standard-model, renormalization, quantum-chromodynamics, strong-force

How can the [strong coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_constant#Weak_and_strong_coupling) constant be measured?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’ll try to explain one method that measures ${{\alpha }_{s}}$ within ±8% at very high energies.  Consider $pp$ or $p\bar{p}$ collisions with CM energy in the TeV range.  What happens in the events of interest is that one “parton” from each of the nucleons participates in hard scattering via single-gluon exchange, and the rest of each nucleon proceeds essentially undisturbed, with a substantial fraction of the nucleon’s initial momentum and <1 GeV/c of deflection.  You should see four distinct jets, two of them along the axis of collision and two at large angles.  The experimental technique involves measuring the 4-momentum of each jet.   The 4-momentum of each deflected parton can be inferred from the different between the momentum of the incoming nucleon and that of the undeflected jet.  The 4-momentum of the gluon can in turn be inferred from the difference between the momentum of the deflected parton and that of the outgoing jet.  Since the differential scattering cross-sections for $qq$ and $q\bar{q}$ are well known, aside from the coefficient, the measured statistics reveal ${{\alpha }_{s}}(t)$.  (Minor complication:  In $qq\to qq$ scattering, there is a *u*-channel process that interferes with the *t*-channel process.)

Answer (score 6):

Through literally hundreds of experiments of dozens of process types, involving the strong interactions, and coordinated comparisons of precision measurements with detailed calculations of Quantum Chromodynamics ([QCD](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/reviews/rpp2018-rev-qcd.pdf)).

In the last 40 years, dozens of ingenious handles for precision determinations have been devised and compared, cf

[image]

[image]