# Calculating strong coupling constant $\alpha_s$

Tags: standard-model, renormalization, quantum-chromodynamics, perturbation-theory, strong-force

I'm trying to find out how to calculate the value of strong [coupling constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_constant). but haven't found any exact answer, all I get is reference to perturbation theory.
is there any exact defined formula to calculate strong coupling constant/ any data set related to it?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/498110/2451

Answer (score 1):

The coupling constant of the strong interaction
(and also those of the other interactions)
is not predicted by the current theory.

Quoted from [Standard model - Challenges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model#Challenges):

> Unsolved problem in physics:
>
> - ...
> - Why do particle masses and coupling constants have the values that we measure?
> - ...

Instead, it can only be determined from experiments,
to give a best fit to the measured data.

Comment: thankyou for your resonse, can you suggest any datasets/ experiments that can help in exploring this domain?

Comment: also does it mean that we can't do the calculations ourselves, measurements for these constants are only done in the labs?

Comment: @maryammalik For experiments follow Qmechanic's link below your question.