# How is strong coupling constant measured through deep inellastic scattering (DIS)?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, interactions, strong-force

is deep inelastic scattering a process? and how is it (DIS) used to measure strong coupling constant?

> the traditional method of measuring $α_S$ in deep inelastic scattering is from the strength of the structure function scaling violations predicted by the DGLAP equations.

how?

Comment: [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/498245/66086) should almost answer your question. Scaling violations enter into the DIS profiles.

Comment: Thankyou, does the  method explained in this answer is DIS?

Comment: The [link](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/reviews/rpp2018-rev-qcd.pdf) in my answer covers DGLAP in DIS, of course.

Comment: can you reattach the link as this one isnt opening and is giving error.

Comment: Here is the Durham [mirror site](http://durpdg.dur.ac.uk/lbl/2020/reviews/rpp2020-rev-qcd.pdf).